# How do I remove an obsolete bot in xcode

Tags: xcode, server, bots

After updating XCode Server I get the following message :

> "this bot is not supported in this version of xcode"

I can't find any way to delete these old bots. Does anyone know how I can do such a thing? Here is a screenshot of the available actions.

[image: Example of allowed actions]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a property list that stores all the bots configuration at:

**~/Library/Developer/XCode/UserData/ServerBots.plist**

You can just remove the ones that are obsolete from there and restart XCode.

If you want to remove all of the items just replace the contents of your file by this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array/>
</plist>
```

Comment: You rocks! It is a very powerful answer. It is such a pain to destroy and recreate bot at each update of XCode.

Comment: @Vaseltior, I am glad I was useful :)

Comment: Does anybody know where the bots are stored on Xcode 7 / Server 5.0.x ?

Answer (score 4):

If you're stuck trying to delete whole servers, this is possible in `Preferences -> Accounts`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I just recreated bots with the same name again and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

All is needed is to download the XCode version the bots were created with and use this version to delete the old bots.